# Unable to select data from another joined table

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I have some tables with huge data, so I try to use that data to create a kind of a report, based on some conditions using `LEFT JOIN',

```
SELECT SUBSIDIARY, MAIN_ACCOUNT, AMOUNT ... FROM (
...
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAIN_ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT_NO AS SUBSIDIARY FROM TABLE1 WHERE STATUS = 'A') K
ON MAIN_ACCOUNT = K.MAIN_ACCOUNT
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT, ACCOUNT_NO, FROM TABLE2 WHERE ACCOUNT_NO = K.ACCOUNT_NO GROUP_BY ACCOUNT_NO) L
ON SUBSIDIARY = L.ACCOUNT_NO --this is where i got into a problem
...
);
```

The problem is that I cannot access the `K.ACCOUNT_NO` from another join I have tried using `WHERE ACCOUNT_NO = SUBSIDIARY` since I select in the main `SELECT`. Does it mean that I cannot access previously queried data from another join?

Error I get:

```
ORA-00904: "SUBSIDIARY": invalid identifier
```

if I use `k.subsidiary` or `k.account_no`

```
ORA-00904: "k.SUBSIDIARY": invalid identifier
ORA-00904: "k.account_no": invalid identifier
```

Comment: @GurwinderSingh updated error messages

Comment: Your question cannot be effectively answered as is because you have ambiguous columns you are selecting. In your first LEFT JOIN, you say `ON MAIN_ACCOUNT = K.MAIN_ACCOUNT`. Where is that first one referring to coming from? Go back through and fully qualify all of the fields you are selecting. That process might actually help you find where the problem is. If it doesn't, edit your post to show the result and that will help clarify where the problem is.

Comment: @SandPiper that first `MAIN_ACCOUNT` comes from other tables, I didn't include it in question since it will bring more confusion, and I do not think it is important of where it comes from

Comment: I suspected that, but here's the problem. It's still ambiguous. Qualify your fields, I promise it will help at least you.

Comment: @SandPiper thanks I will try next time to be less ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access the `K.ACCOUNT_NO` but you can `INNER JOIN` with `TABLE1`.

```
WHERE ACCOUNT_NO = K.ACCOUNT_NO
```

is replaced

```
INNER JOIN TABLE1 ON TABLE2.ACCOUNT_NO = TABLE1.ACCOUNT_NO AND TABLE1.STATUS = 'A'
```

I hope it is helpful.

```
SELECT SUBSIDIARY, MAIN_ACCOUNT, AMOUNT ... FROM (
    ...
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAIN_ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT_NO AS SUBSIDIARY FROM TABLE1 WHERE STATUS = 'A') K
    ON MAIN_ACCOUNT = K.MAIN_ACCOUNT
    --this is where i got into a problem
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT, ACCOUNT_NO, FROM TABLE2 INNER JOIN TABLE1 ON TABLE2.ACCOUNT_NO = TABLE1.ACCOUNT_NO AND TABLE1.STATUS = 'A' GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NO) L
    ON SUBSIDIARY = L.ACCOUNT_NO
    ...
    );
```